# untar changes permissions of target directory... how to prevent?

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, tar

I have the following:

```
$ls -la
drwxrwxr-x   3    pi    pi   4096     Mar 24  14:49    .
...

$chmod o+w .
$ls -la
drwxrwxrwx   3    pi    pi   4096     Mar 24  14:49    .
...

$tar xf myfile.tar
$ls -la
drwxrwxr-x   3    pi    pi   4096     Mar 24  14:49    .
...
```

I.e. after untaring, the current directory looses write permission for "others".

Looks like tar somehow changes it. How to check? May be archive contains entry for `.`? How to exclude it?

Comment: “May be archive contains entry for `.`?” Can’t you check? `tar tvf myfile.tar` will tell you.

Comment: It tells it is there. Is this a reason?

Answer (score 0):

I was creating archive with

```
tar -cvf ../$filename.tar .
```

when I started to create with

```
tar -cvf ../$filename.tar ./*
```

the problem is gone.